# RouteLink without link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there some way of generating the link from the route-table without making it a link?

i.e only www.foo.com/someroute/34   without it being linked

/M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [RouteUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl.aspx) extension method:

```
<%= Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { id = 75 }) %>
```

And if you want an absolute url:

```
<%= Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { id = 75 }, Request.Url.Scheme) %>
```